# Change whole string when substring contains certain chars

Tags: java, android

If a string of a barcode scan (f.e.) contains "CZC" I want to be able to change the whole string into (f.e.) "LOKO".

---

```
if (data != null) {
                    Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
                    statusMessage.setText("Strichcode erfolgreich gelesen");
                    barcodeValue.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Strichcode Scannen: " + barcode.displayValue);
```

---

This part and more of the code that I have already written is supposed to change the whole string if "CZC" is contained.

Comment: Question: You need to detect if string contains substring. If yes set barcode value to whatever you want. Just use `"someCZCtect".contains("CZC")`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String bc = barcode.displayValue
if (bc.contains("CZV")) {
    bc = "LOKO";
}
barcodeValue.setText(bc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String bc = barcode.displayValue
bc = bc.contains("CZV") ? "LOKO" : bc;
barcodeValue.setText(bc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains` function:

```
String myString = barcode.displayvalue;
if(myString.contains("CZC")){
    myString = "replaced";
}
```